# Restrict picking minimum and maximum date with vanilla javascript for hotel reservation

Tags: javascript, date, validation, datepicker, mindate

I have a form for hotel reservation. I just need to validate the checkin date and the checkout date, don‘t look for a whole booking engine either.

I have 2 input date fields, one for CHECKIN, the other for CHECKOUT. The minimum CHECKIN date should be 2 days after the current day, and the minimum CHECKOUT date, 3 days after the current day.

I made two blocks of javascript, one for the CHECKIN date and the other for the CHECKOUT. As per I noticed that the CHECKOUT script block works, but no the first one, I changed the variable names for the second block and this is still working. The input date for the checkout is set well.

Each block have different ID target to each of the fields (checkin and checkout). I‘d like to know why one block is overriding the other one and don‘t want to allow the user to select a checkout date previous to the checkin date which will be an absurd.

Here is my code:

```js
// Scripts for CHECKIN date
function formatISOLocal(d) {
  let z = n => ('0' + n).slice(-2);
  return d.getFullYear() + '-' + z(d.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + z(d.getDate());
}

window.onload = function() {
  let inp = document.querySelector('#checkIn');
  let d = new Date();
  d.setDate(d.getDate() + 2); /*Minimum date for CHECKIN*/
  console.log(formatISOLocal(d));
  inp.min = formatISOLocal(d);
  inp.defaultValue = inp.min;
  d.setMonth(d.getMonth() + 3);
  inp.max = formatISOLocal(d);
}

// Scripts for CHECKOUT date
function formatISOLocal1(e) {
  let a = o => ('0' + o).slice(-2);
  return e.getFullYear() + '-' + a(e.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + a(e.getDate());
}

window.onload = function() {
  let out = document.querySelector('#checkOut');
  let e = new Date();
  e.setDate(e.getDate() + 3); /*Minimum date for CHECKOUT*/
  out.min = formatISOLocal1(e);
  out.defaultValue = out.min;
  e.setMonth(e.getMonth() + 4);
  out.max = formatISOLocal1(e);
}
```

```html
<input type="date" id="checkIn" name="checkIn" required>
<input type="date" id="checkOut" name="checkOut" required>
```

I also share my [codepen](https://codepen.io/limakid/pen/QWmjjQj?editors=1000). Orientations, please.

Answer (score 1):

The second *window.onload* overwrites the first so it never runs. Combine the code into one *onload* and use only one *formatISOLocal*, e.g.

```js
function formatISOLocal(d) {
  let z = n => ('0' + n).slice(-2);
  return d.getFullYear() + '-' + z(d.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + z(d.getDate());
}

window.onload = function() {
  let inp = document.querySelector('#checkIn');
  let d = new Date();
  d.setDate(d.getDate() + 2); /*Minimum date for CHECKIN*/
  console.log(formatISOLocal(d));
  inp.min = formatISOLocal(d);
  inp.defaultValue = inp.min;
  d.setMonth(d.getMonth() + 3);
  inp.max = formatISOLocal(d);

  let out = document.querySelector('#checkOut');
  let e = new Date();
  e.setDate(e.getDate() + 3); /*Minimum date for CHECKOUT*/
  out.min = formatISOLocal(e);
  out.defaultValue = out.min;
  e.setMonth(e.getMonth() + 4);
  out.max = formatISOLocal(e);
}
```

```html
<input type="date" id="checkIn" name="checkIn" required>
<input type="date" id="checkOut" name="checkOut" required>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a script that will set the minimum of the second date to the first date

```js
var a = document.getElementById("a");
var b = document.getElementById("b");

a.addEventListener("input", function() {
  b.min = a.value;
});

a.min = new Date().getFullYear()+"-"+new Date().getDate()+"-"+(new Date().getMonth()+1);
```

```html
<input type="date" id="a"> From<br>
<input type="date" id="b"> To
```

Comment: For 5 July 2022, that will produce a date like "2022-5-7".  Not sure any web standards compliant system is going to be able to parse that as you expect. It's not a format supported by ECMA-262. So unlikely to work. And why use the input event? Surely just setting the min attribute once the "from" date is selected is simpler? And what if the to date is selected before the from date? And so on…

Comment: @RobG, yes I saw in the site of Booking dot com, if you select a FROM date like July 5th and then try to select a TO date like June 30th, the FROM date will automatically reset to June 29th to void this kind of “time travelers”.  And also, the calendar widget for the TO date shows up ONLY if you have set up a From date, but actually, that‘s a high level validation; I just was planing to set an error message in case FROM-date > TO-date.

Comment: @RobG That is the standard for the date input type, how would you detect when the from date is entered without events in vanilla js?

Comment: I was questioning the use of the input event. It's dispatched effectively on keypress and means events are likely to be dispatched before the user has finished entering the entire date they wish to enter. E.g. if the value is say "28/02/2000" and the user wants to enter "31/07/2000" then they will likely type "31" first, so temporarily have "31/02/2000" as the input's value. Since that's an invalid date, what will the other input's value be set to? Etc.

Comment: @RobG That may be an issue for type=number for example but not for type=date as most modern browsers will give you a calendar UI, even then you can just update things on the fly and it won't break anything by the time they get to the to section

Comment: @Player_X_YT—that does not stop a user from entering the date manually, which many users prefer to do, especially when they know the date they wish to enter and don't want to click through months or even years to get there. E.g. someone 70 years old entering their birthday when the default is today's date.